# One word for responsibility to take care of something/someone who relies on

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I do have some *family financial concerns, responsibility to take care of something/someone who relies on me*. So I am in such a situation, that I have a lot of..... (duties,burden,reponsibilities,liabilities). Which is the suitable one word for that?

Comment: *responsibilities* or *dependencies* would suffice, I think.

Comment: I feel like you've answered your own question: "responsibilities" seems like a good fit to me, and it's right there in the title!

Comment: @MamtaD, if you have many responsibilities to other people, you might have "dependents", but wouldn't you having "dependency"/"dependencies" mean that _you_ are the one relying on someone else?

Comment: @Yee-Lum As per [this site](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dependencies) it seems to be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***obligation***

> : something (as a formal contract, a promise, or the demands of
>   conscience or custom) that obligates one to a course of action [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obligation)

***commitment***

> : a promise to do or give something
>
> : a promise to be loyal to someone or something
>
> : the attitude of someone who works very hard to do or support
>   something [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commitment)

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[domestic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/domestic) duties/responsibilities*** is the expression you need:

> - of or relating to the running of a home or to family relations.

(ODO)